# Not receiving data for second GET TCP request

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am opening the TCP connection(in python) only once like this

```
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
```

The server correctly responds when I send a GET request like this for the first time

```
sentence = "GET "+ requestUrl +" HTTP/1.1\r\n"+ "Connection: Keep-Alive" +"\r\n\r\n"
    clientSocket.send(sentence)
```

But when I send a GET request using the same syntax the second time(without closing the connection), I get a blank response.
I am retrieving the response as :-

```
getImage=""

    while True:
        data=clientSocket.recv(1024)
        if(not data):
            break
        getImage+=data
```

Can anyone please help with this ?

Comment: Are you certain that you should expect a response from subsequent requests using this same socket?  If so, how do you know?

Comment: Yes the request is a get for a css file which i have tested in chrome

Comment: Compare the traffic that chrome generates with the traffic that your program generates using `wireshark` or a similar packet trace tool.  You're bound to see a distinction in the actual interaction.

Comment: Apart from that the request is wrong. HTTP/1.1 request require a Host header.

Comment: Adding a Host header does not help

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the whole response server did send to you as a result?

Comment: I have added my code for data retrieval

Comment: Umm, your code to receive an HTTP response doesn't have any idea what an HTTP response *is*. How could it possibly work? If you're going to claim HTTP 1.1 compliance, you have to actually implement HTTP 1.1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as I expected, your receiving code has a bug.You are doing blocking recv() calls untill you see nothing. On the other end, the server is sending you the data and than waits for some time for new requests on the connection. After timeout, server closes connection and your recv() code returns with no data. You are sending another GET request on closed connection, which of course does nothing.

The proper way of doing this is to read how many bytes the server is going to send you in HTTP Response header, read as many bytes and than issue new request.

Comment: Can you please help me retrieve the response length ?

Comment: It is a part of HTTP Response header. What help do you need?

Comment: to read the HTTP response header I will have to still have to do a recv with some buffer size ,say 1024, right ?

Comment: That's not sufficient for HTTP 1.1 compliance. For example, if you read the HTTP 1.1 specification, it says that a "[recipient MUST be able to parse and decode the chunked transfer coding](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-4.1)".You have to actually write code to implement the HTTP 1.1 specification. Really.

Comment: @DeepankarArya After each call to `recv`, you have to decide whether you have received a complete HTTP 1.1 response or not. If you have, don't call `recv` again. That means you have to at least understand all the rules for determining when an HTTP 1.1 response is complete. That means understanding how to tell all the ways HTTP 1.1 permits the end of a response to be indicated. There are four (end of header with no body, chunked encoding, length specified in header, end marked by connection close). You will need to understand the HTTP 1.1 specification to implement an HTTP 1.1 client.